# How do I make the maven jetty plugin aware of an additional web directory?

Tags: javascript, maven, jetty

I would like to use src/main/javascript as the source directory for my javascript files while still using src/main/webapp for most other web files but the maven jetty:run plugin does not know about this directory by default.

The following is as far as I've gotten so far but it does not seem to make Jetty aware of my javascript directory:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.12</version>
      <configuration>
        <webAppConfig>
          <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
          <extraClasspath>target/classes/:src/main/javascript</extraClasspath>
        </webAppConfig> 
        <webResources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <directory>src/main/javascript</directory>
          </resource>
        </webResources>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

How do I make the maven jetty plugin aware of this addtional web directory?

Comment: I wish I could give this question and answer +10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this could help you:

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Multiple+WebApp+Source+Directory

So i'd amend your configuration as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.12</version>
  <configuration>
    <webAppConfig>
      <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
      <!-- Javascript files are not java class files, so you can skip this
      <extraClasspath>target/classes/:src/main/javascript</extraClasspath>
      -->
      <baseResource implementation="org.mortbay.resource.ResourceCollection">
        <resourcesAsCSV>src/main/webapp,src/main/javascript</resourcesAsCSV>
      </baseResource>
    </webAppConfig> 
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I can't get that to work. I get this error from maven:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.12:run (default-cli) on project myproject: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.12:run for parameter resources: Cannot assign configuration entry 'resources' with value 'src/main/webapp,src/main/javascript' of type java.lang.String to property of type org.mortbay.resource.Resource[] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Ok, the docs page says to use resourcesAsCSV if this fails, i've updated and asserted it works for me

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `ResourceCollection` class has moved in the latest version of Jetty (9.3.0.M2).

Therefore, the implementation should point at `org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.0.M2</version>
  <configuration>
    <webAppConfig>
      <baseResource implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection">
        <resourcesAsCSV>src/main/webapp,src/main/javascript</resourcesAsCSV>
      </baseResource>
    </webAppConfig> 
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of [Jetty 9](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-your-webapp):

```
<webApp>
  <contextPath>/my-app</contextPath>
  <resourceBases>
    <resourceBase>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</resourceBase>
    <resourceBase>${project.basedir}/external-static</resourceBase>
  </resourceBases>
</webApp>
```